# Wordpress Workflow - version control, deployment = database issue

Tags: deployment, version-control, workflow

I'm trying to work version control into developing a Wordpress site, but I'm unable to solve the issue of DB synchronization.

For simplicity's sake, I will describe a scenario with just Live and Staging websites and repos:

1. Pull down Live DB to Staging DB
2. Do the same for code
3. Install WP plugin on Staging. Tweak, configure and test as needed.
4. When ready, deploy to Live <- here is the issue

The installation of the plugin could result in changes to the database. New tables and maybe even new entries in existing tables. Of course, pushing up the code part of the plugin is not an issue, but what about the DB changes? The Live DB has already changed (it's a live site after all). That means I'm stuck back at square one - installing a plugin directly on Live without proper testing and deployment workflow.

All the articles I've read that talk about putting WP under source control and proper deployment practices don't seem to say anything about this issue. Am I just missing something obvious entirely?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What changes to the DB are you needing to go live?

Comment: Never mind, I see you are concerned about the changes a plugin/theme/core might make to the database.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to try and avoid relaying on configuration changes via the admin interface. Don't use plugins that you can not configure by filtering options, or better, use only those that have an official API and use the API.

For example if a plugin has an option "pl_option" with which you are happy when its value is 5, do not change the option in the DB via the admin but set it to 5 by using a filter like

```
add_filter('get_option_pl_option', function () {return 5;});
```

if in the next version of the plugin the DB structure changes to be an array, you change you code to something like

```
add_filter('get_option_pl_option', function () {return array('value'=>5;});
```

This obviously do not prevent from the plugin to make DB changes, but makes your code agnostic to them.

Anyway, having the code in a version control is a small win in any case even if following the suggestion above is not realistic for you.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. WordPress itself makes DB changes. Many of the best plugins available make DB changes.

Comment: It doesn't make sense because the second rate quality of most wordpress plugins and themes got you used to follow second rate development workflow. The OP asks about the proper workflow, not about the easy workflow. As for wordpress core upgrades, you have a point, but 1. this is unavoidable risk when working with wordpress and 2.you can trust core to not do breaking changes, or changes that require additional configuration. For all other plugins, even from just semi respectable authors, there will be filters and APIs you can use, just need to read the documentation.

Comment: Sometimes plugins have to make changes to data structure to maintain code. Does that make sense? Yes! Does that make the plugin second rate? No! There is simple protocol for this to happen. What doesn't make sense is having to write your own filters for data changes.

Comment: @NathanPowell, I seriously don't understand what is it that you don't understand. If there are plugins that "have to make DB changes" then don't use them if you want to have a good workflow, use only plugins that provide official APIs.

Comment: What don't you understand? Plugins, themes and WP core make database changes depending on the version you are using. Official (and even unofficial) APIs are how you interact with the data stored. Most themes and plugins change that too. But we aren't talking about that are we?

Comment: Point is, you CAN NOT avoid database changes between versions of code. The code you rely on will do it for you, otherwise it's "second rate". It might actually be great really, and a bug report was missed.

Comment: @NathanPowell, Good plugins will have APIS that are DB agnostic (shortcodes and widgets usually can be used in isolation from the DB), for many other plugin you can filter the option value returned from the DB, making what ever changes being done non important at all.

Comment: Pardon my pretentiousness. I thought we were talking about plugins that do rely on the database. Like all the ones that store data.

Comment: seriously @NathanPowell, you don't have to show your lack of understanding how wordpress and plugins works so many times in one comment thread

Comment: Really? I'll be fine. You haven't shown your knowledge at all either. Just keep trolling dude.

Comment: Honestly you misunderstood the question. The OP wants to know if the database changes that plugins intended to make will happen if he simply installs the code. My answer told him that. Yours makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46144/discussion-between-nathan-powell-and-mark-kaplun).

Comment: the OP is confused because the recommendation is to use GIT for code development, but obviously when you add a plugin, or upgrade it, you might need to perform some configuration changes in order to keep it performing the same way, or maybe get it performing better. Those configuration changes are not going to be documented in GIT and will not "automatically" be applied to the production when a "pull" of the code is done. My answer is not about preventing DB changes (as you say, it is unavoidable) but controlling the plugin functionality from code instead of DB.

Comment: since most plugins keep the configuration in an option, you can achieve this by filtering the value `get_option` returns for that option and therefor making the settings controlled in your code instead of whatever is in the DB. Maybe I should explain it better in the answer

Comment: I would appreciate that. I am deleting my own answer since it does not apply. I'll kill the downvote as soon as this answer makes sense too ;)

Comment: I misunderstood the OP question.